# Know the stage where error occured while compiling C code

Tags: c, gcc

I am using gcc to compile my C code. Just out of curiosity I would like to know at exactly which stage did the error occur. Is there a way to print this information when compilation error occurs?

Comment: What do you mean by "stage"? I'm not aware of the C language defining any specific stages in which errors can occur.

Comment: @unwind: I mean the different stages like preprocessor, assembler, linker.

Comment: If you understand the error correctly, you should not have any trouble  to know when it happened. Also, linker error will come from ld, not gcc.

Comment: clang is better at issuing understandable error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been commented above, if you understand the message, you should have no problem in deciding where the message came from (preprocessor, assembler, compiler or linker). However, to answer your question, these three stages can be separated easily with a few compiler options passed to `gcc`.

The first option you might try is `-E`. Passing `-E` will stop `gcc` after the preprocessing stage, and the output is simply the preprocessed C code. If your error message appears there, it is generated by the preprocessor. Otherwise, read on.

The second option is `-S`. This will stop GCC after the preprocessing and compilation but before assembling and linking. If you see your error message at this stage, it is generated by either the preprocessor (but you excluded that already in the previous step) or the compiler. Otherwise, read on.

The third and last option to try is `-c`. Passing `-c` will ask GCC to preprocess, compile and assemble the source files, but do not link. If you see your error message at this stage, it is generated by either the preprocessor or the compiler (but you excluded those already in the previous step), or the assembler. Otherwise it comes from the linker.

Answer (score 1):

This already happens.

```
#ifedf THIS
    that;
#Endif

$gcc ifed.c
ifed.c:1:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #ifedf
ifed.c:2:5: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
ifed.c:3:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #Endif

int main() {
    int int, int;
}

$ gcc mai.c
mai.c: In function ‘main’:
mai.c:2:9: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
mai.c:2:12: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘,’ token

int main() {
    bogusfunction();
}

gcc lin.c
/tmp/ccUc0WAL.o:lin.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_bogusfunction'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```